# Significance of Hahn-Banach theorem.

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, intuition, motivation, hahn-banach-theorem

I am doing a course on functional analysis. One of the pillars in functional analysis is Hahn-Banach theorem. But in different books I find different versions of the theorem and it is not easy to check that they are equivalent. So, I want to understand why Hahn-Banach theorem is important. Also the proof uses Zorn's lemma which is equivalent to axiom of choice, so I cannot understand it by concrete examples. The statement given by our instructor for Hahn-Banach theorem is as follows:

> Let $X$ be a normed linear space and $X_0$ be a subspace of $X$,let $f_0$ be a bounded linear functional on $X_0$,then there is a bounded linear functional $f$ on $X$ such that $f|_{X_0}=f_0$ and $||f||=||f_0||$ i.e. $\sup\limits_{||x||=1,x\in X}|f(x)|=\sup\limits_{||x||=1,x\in X_0}|f_0(x)|$.

I want to understand the usefulness of the fact that $||f||=||f_0||,$ i.e. its physical significance and why it is good to have such an extension. Can someone give me some idea?

Comment: One consequence is that if $0\ne x\in X$ then there exists $f\in X^*$ with $f(x)\ne0$.  And $X^*$ separates points of $X$: If $x,y\in X$ and $x\ne y$ then there exists $f\in X^*$ with $f(x)\ne f(y).$ In the  case where $x,y$ are linearly independent, this is a special case of a more general consequence of H-B: If $C$ is a vector-subspace of $X$ and $x\in X \setminus \overline C$ then there exists $f\in X^*$ with $f[C]=\{0\}$ and $f(x)\ne 0.$

Comment: My edit was for some trivial typos (||x||| for ||x||) and spaces. The machine is happier when you put a space after a comma or period. BTW, \|x\| instead of ||x|| gives a better look.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I did not know that $\|x\|$ works.Thanks